# Windows computer with contradictory CPU readings

Tags: windows-10, memory, cpu-usage

Disclaimer before I begin: I'm giving tech support to my father in a different country over Zoom, so I don't have easy access to his computer, and I may take a while to respond to further info requests :-D

So, my dad bought a new Windows laptop from some online store, and it's not even 2 months old and it's giving trouble with freezes. I got on a Zoom call with him now, and the first thing I see is that he's got a whopping 3.4 GB RAM :-p. Welp, that's probably the problem, I reckoned.

And it may be. But there's some other very weird behavior that puts some doubt on the matter. Firstly, his memory usage is high, but generally not over 80%, even during the Zoom call. Of course, throw in a Chrome tab with Gmail, and that'll grow pretty fast.

But what's really got me confused is his CPU readings. Here's the performance tab of the Task Manager:
[image]
Note: 100% CPU usage, but memory hanging around 79%.
So I wanted to find out more about which apps are hogging the CPU, and went to the "Details" tab:
[image]
Wait...what?! 45% idle CPU? And that wasn't just an outlier. The Idle process was sitting between 40-60% the whole time I was watching it.
Ok, let's dive into the Resource Monitor:
[image]
And now I'm even more confused. CPU is at 115% (I guess that means processes are being queued for CPU)...but that CPU column there, sorted from highest to lowest, is *no way* going to make it up to 100%. Summing the numbers on screen (the only processes that round up to 1% CPU or higher) doesn't even make 50%!

So what is going on here?

1. Why are these CPU usage numbers internally contradictory?
2. What is using all the CPU?
3. Can I blame the computer's unreliability on low memory, or might there be some other malady at work here?

Comment: The CPU might be used for memory compression. Check for that in the performance tab to see if data in memory is being compressed. Post that, please.

Comment: Idle means the percentage of cpu Not being used.

Comment: "Can I blame the computer's unreliability on low memory, or might there be some other malady at work here?" - The system's main problem is the low end CPU, it only have 4 GB of memory, is only one of the problems with it.

Comment: @eventHandler Actually yes, I did notice that there was a "Memory Compression" row high up on one of the tabs in the Resource Monitor, though I didn't take a screen shot of it. What does it mean?

Comment: @Ramhound What do you mean by "low end CPU"?

Comment: @Moab I know what Idle means. How do you reconcile 50% Idle with the fact that the overall reported CPU usage is over 100%?

Comment: @ShaulBehr - `AMD 3020E` is a low end low power dual core mobile processor.

Comment: @Ramhound Low end is fine in this case. My dad uses it for email and the occasional spreadsheet. It just has to work...

Comment: Memory compression is a feature introduced in Windows 10 similar to disk paging, but intended to avoid disk usage. It particularly compresses memory when you are running low, and compression requires CPU. It might not be the only problem, but could explain part of the differences in the readings.

Comment: @eventHandler So then expanding the physical memory could make a big difference to that, right?

Comment: @ShaulBehr - You provided a screenshot of Task Manager but had the CPU selected instead of memory.  However, at the time of the screenshot, you still had most of your memory free.  Additional system memory will not make the system "faster" since your CPU usage is a serious problem on that system.

Comment: @Ramhound It was suggested above that Memory Compression may be the culprit here, and that the CPU is only churning like this because it's trying to compress memory the whole time. It wouldn't need to do that if there were more physical memory. Or have I got that wrong?

Comment: Memory Compression cannot be disabled on Windows 10.  So memory compression will happen regardless, likely around the same amount of memory, will be compressed at any given time.  The only difference is you will just have more memory available.  However, free memory isn't a problem, your system has 700 MB free already.  It probably has more than that, but I can't tell, based on the screenshots you provided.  In any event there is a good chance that the memory installed within the device cannot be upgraded.  I will again point out this device is low power dual core processor

Comment: @Ramhound ok, so if I've understood you correctly, Memory Compression is an attempt to prevent disk usage. But disk usage is only a fallback for when you have low memory available. So surely then MC is the same? And if there were sufficient physical memory on the device, would MC not be able to take a vacation, and leave the CPU alone?

Comment: @ShaulBehr - MC will happen regardless if you have 8 GB or 64 GB on Windows 10